# How to use ceylon code in a web page?

Tags: ceylon

I'm trying to use javaSCript in a web page according to this [tutorial](http://ceylon-lang.org/blog/2013/02/26/ceylon-in-the-browser/) ceylon.language-1.2.0-model.js. Where can I get that. Also is there an easier way than what is described in that tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find that file here : http://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0

And we're currently working on making it somewhat easier to do what that tutorial describes, but that will have to wait for version 1.2.1 (which won't take too long to come out hopefully)